# How can we implement multiple custom action filters in web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-webapi

How can we implement multiple custom action filters in web api?

```
public class FileValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}

public class ModelStateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ApiException(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add `[FileValidation]` and `[ModelStateFilter]` together.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to register those attributes in the `services (Dependency Injection)`.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .
    .
    services.AddScoped<FileValidationAttribute>();
    services.AddScoped<ModelStateFilterAttribute>();
    .
    .
}
```

Use `ServiceFilter` attribute to call two filters in same action method.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet("TestAction")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(FileValidationAttribute))]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ModelStateFilterAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestAction()
{
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Refer this link about [`ServiceFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute